# Add 'where' in query with foreach or something similar

Tags: mysql, search, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

this is my problem.

product_field_glue table:

```
id | field_id | value
----------------------
1  | 50       | blue
2  | 51       | wood
3  | 50       | red
4  | 35       | car
```

I need to search products by this fields according _GET params

```
/?field[50][]=blue&field[35][]=car
```

this should return all blue cars

```
$result = Products::select('products.*')
 ->leftJoin('product_field_glue', function ($join) {
      $join->on('product_field_glue.product_code', '=', 'products.product_code');
        })
 ->where(function($query) use ($id, $value){
            $query->where('product_fields.field_id', $id);
            $query->where('product_fields.value', $value);
        })
```

This is modified (part of) query. As you can see I need to set 'where' for all `_GET['field']` and `$key=>$value` of GET parameter need to be in grouped where.
Maybe there is better solution for this kind of search which you can recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#query-scopes) for this.

Inside your `Products` class:

```php
/**
 * Warning: requires a join on product_field_glue table
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @param  array  $fields
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeSearchFields($query, $fields) {
    if (empty($fields)) {
        return $query;
    }

    foreach ($fields as $id => $values) {
        $query = $query->where(function ($subquery) use($id, $values) {
            $subquery->where('product_field_glue.field_id', $id);
            $subquery->whereIn('product_field_glue.value', $values);
        });
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Notice that the method is called `scopeSearchFields`. You can attach it to any `Products` query as a chained `searchFields` method:

```
$result = Products::select('products.*')
    ->leftJoin('product_field_glue', function ($join) {
        $join->on('product_field_glue.product_code', '=', 'products.product_code');
    })
    ->searchFields($request->input('fields'))
    ->get();
```

The beauty of this is that it's extremely reusable and keeps all of the `if` and `for` loops inside of the scope method.